# How to populate data for existing documents after new fields are added in mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-7

recently we came across a requirement where we need to add 3 new fields to our Existing Index. We pull this data from our source database using logstash. We have 1000's of documents stored in the current Index already. In the past, it was being told that whenever a change has happened to an existing index (such as adding a new field) we need to reindex with complete data reload again. Since we want the previous documents to have these new fields with data populated in them.

**Is there any other way we can achieve this by not dropping the existing index or deleting any documents and reloading?** I was hoping we can have a better way of doing this with the latest 7. X version.

Answer (score 2):

No need to drop the index and recreate one. After you have updated the mapping of the index, you just upsert the documents in the index again, with the new fields. Each document will be overwritten by the new one.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Comment: references are helpful. we will go through that. thank you.